# Stop image-view by using animation on particular screen position

Tags: android, eclipse

This is what I have done now I want to stop this animation on a particular screen position and I know during the animation it could not stop so please provide another way where I could implement this functionality in my app.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
    <translate
        android:toYDelta="100%p"
        android:duration="6000"
        android:fillEnabled="false"
        android:startOffset="5000"
        android:fillAfter="false"/>
</set>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to give `android:fromXDelta="" 
android:toXDelta=""
android:fromYDelta=""
android:toYDelta=""`

Comment: If any one's answer helps you then you should give a mark to it or should add + to it